# how do i solve plugin error for index.js in cypress

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, cypress, node-modules

I am getting following error for Cypress

The following error was thrown by a plugin. We stopped running your tests because a plugin crashed. Please check your plugins file (/home/dev2/Desktop/kavitaSeffcon/CypressProject/cypress/plugins/index.js)

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/initrd.img'

can please suggest exact solution for this error

Answer (score 0):

Alright so during the troubleshoot our goal would be to reach the nearest version of node required as we can see in below error logs.

-bash-3.2$ npm updatenpm WARN old lockfilenpm WARN old lockfile The package-lock.json file was created with an old version of npm,npm WARN old lockfile so supplemental metadata must be fetched from the registry.npm WARN old lockfilenpm WARN old lockfile This is a one-time fix-up, please be patient...npm WARN old lockfilenpm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: undefined,npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '14.17.0' },npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v17.2.0', npm: '8.1.0' }npm WARN EBADENGINE }

added 7 packages, removed 6 packages, changed 57 packages, and audited 350 packages in 11s

64 packages are looking for fundingrun npm fund for details

added 7 packages, removed 6 packages, changed 57 packages, and audited 350 packages in 11s

64 packages are looking for funding

run `npm fund` for details

As we currently have 17.2.0 and the required is 14.17.0. To fix this

npm cache clearnpm cache clean --forcenpm install -g cypresssudo n 14.17.0rm -rf **put your existing version**.   {Perform this in the folder where your previous version of node was installed}

Open a new terminal

node -v npm installnpx cypress open

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).